# Libraries from Cocoapod are not found by Xcode compiler

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a project that has the Podfile with the following configuration

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'CDA' do
  pod 'RestKit',    '~> 0.27.0'
  pod 'ZBarSDK',    '~> 1.3.1'
end
```

I use the Pod install command and I get the following result

[image: Text]

But when I try to build the project on Xcode, I received the following error:

[image: Text]

For some reason, the compiler was not able to find the libraries from cocoapod.
How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the problem.

I follow the guide on this site
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

What fix the problem for me is the step number 5.

I add the Libraries direct to build now and at the moment it works now for me, all builds are working now.